# How to query elements with repeating?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider table

```
CREATE TABLE `contact` (
    `id`    INTEGER,
    `name`  TEXT,
    `category`  INTEGER,
    `freed` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I want to make such a query or view, that will duplicate rows with `freed = 1 AND caregory IS NOT NULL`, for those rows category should be set to -1. Rows with `(category is null and freed = 1)` should be removed.

First picture shows data source. Second picture show desired result.
3 new rows should be  added ( Jin,-1,1|Tih,-1,1|Traph,-1,1)
1 raw was souldbe remove (Traph, null, 1)

[image]

```
    WHERE NOT(category is null and freed = 1)
    ORDER BY category IS NULL ASC, category = -1 ASC, category ASC , name ASC
```

[image]

Is it possible to make something like

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT s.name, s.category, s.freed
FROM contact s
CASE freed = 1 and category is not null 
    insert into v1(t.name,-1,1) 
    SELECT p.name
    FROM contact p
    WHERE s.name = p.name
```

Comment: No its not but it is possible like I posted in my answer. View represent a select query, it cannot update or insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need is something like:

```
INSERT INTO CONTACT 
(SELECT Name,-1,1 FROM CONTACT
WHERE CATEGORY IS NOT NULL AND FREED = 1)
```

And a delete:

```
DELETE FROM CONTACT
WHERE CATEGORY IS NULL AND FREED = 1
```

Or if you want it in a query then:

```
SELECT Name,-1,1 FROM CONTACT
WHERE CATEGORY IS NOT NULL AND FREED = 1
UNION 
select nam,ecategory,freed
FROM CONTACT
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the values, then:

```
select name, category, freed
from contact c
where category is null and freed = 1
union all
select name, -1, freed
from contact
where category is not null and freed = 1;
```

The main issue is getting a proper `id` value.  This is a bit tricky in SQLite, and your example with "backfilled" numbers is not going to be easily to implement at all.

Comment: Please look at updated bottom of question. Is it possible to make such view?